# Mule - Handling Fixed-Width Input Format with Datawaeve

Tags: mule, mule-studio

Mule ESB Studio 3.6 Data mapper had a feature to process fixed width input format from files [reflink](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/datamapper-fixed-width-input-format), but that option is not available in Mule Anypoint Studio 5.4.0 Data Weave which is mentioned as upgraded feature of Data Mapper, but how to process the fixed width input format with Data weave ?

**Solution:**

Anypoint Studio version 5.4

http://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/35622/finding-datamapper-in-new-anypointstudio-ui.html

QUICK Look:

Once you open Studio, use the menu option and go to Window > Preferences > Palette Profiles and check Show deprecated Mule components and attributes. Click Apply. At this point you should be able to find DataMapper in the palette.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed Width format support for DataWeave will be available with Mule 3.8.0 and not in the current 3.7.

Comment: your are mentioning Mule 3.8.0 runtime right? i am looking for datamapper connector in Anypoint Studio 5+

Comment: @jerith2 yes 3.8.0 runtime. Since DataWeave was introduced, datamapper is no longer included in studio by default. You would need to download it as a plugin from support portal and then install it in your studio. Have you tried that - https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/including-the-datamapper-plugin. It is available only to Enterprise edition.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with is available in latest release 3.8.0,You can also use xslt if you dont want to upgrade your runtime

Answer (score 0):

Anypoint Studio version 5.4

http://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/35622/finding-datamapper-in-new-anypointstudio-ui.html

QUICK Look:

Once you open Studio, use the menu option and go to Window > Preferences > Palette Profiles and check Show deprecated Mule components and attributes. Click Apply. At this point you should be able to find DataMapper in the palette.